# is it possible to develop R package by using multiple subfolders under folder R

Tags: r, makefile, devtools, r-package

I would like to develop an R package with multiple subfolders

../R/file1.R
../R/d1/file2.R
../R/d2/file3.R

I want to build the package using all the subfolders under directory R. Is this possible? Does it require a Makevars.wim; if so how do I make Makevars.wim to make sure that all subfolders are compiled during package build

Comment: You cannot use sub folders under the R folder to organize your R code files, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14905225/4468078

Comment: I know the standard routine, but is there a way to get around it by using Makefiles?